# Is there an equivalent of string multiplication in Lua? Eg: "o"*3

Tags: lua

Is there an equivalent of the following code which is in python, in Lua?

```py
print('o'*3)  #=> "ooo"
```

The Lua equivalent of this would be...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
string.rep('o', 3)
```

Or:

```
local my_string = 'o'
my_string:rep(3)
```

Or:

```
('o'):rep(3)
```

(when you use this syntax, literal expressions such as `'o'` must be in parentheses. `'o':rep(3)` is not valid syntax)

Comment: Oh I see. This answers my question. Thank you very much! (For the extra clarification too :D)

Comment: Depending on Lua version a string is metatabled and the __index metamethod is filled up with all string functions. You can see them with: ```do for k,v in pairs(getmetatable(_VERSION).__index) do print(k,'=',v) end end``` Thats the reason why @user253751 last two examples work with the ```:```

Comment: Check this out too: ```_VERSION:gsub('%a',{u='\85\85\85',a='\65\65\65'})```

Comment: @koyaanisqatsi you can also just look in `string` because (IIRC) the `__index` ***is*** `string`

Comment: Yes it is - Therefore i like to do for tables __index table the table table: ```setmetatable(arg,{__index=table})``` then this works with arg: ```arg:concat(' ',0)``` - The ```0``` means: Start with key ```0``` not ```1```